# inner join on cobk and coep tables taking huge time

Tags: performance, abap, opensql

I am trying to join two tables and get data into `covp_itab` internal table  but it is taking a very long time.
Moreover I tried to get the data from database view `COVP` which is defined for both tables, it also took very long.

```
SELECT bk~kokrs
       bk~belnr
       bk~budat
       bk~cpudt
       bk~bltxt
       ep~buzei
       ep~wkgbtr
       ep~objnr
       ep~gjahr
       ep~kstar
       ep~vrgng
       ep~parob1
       ep~beknz
       ep~sgtxt
       ep~objnr_n1
       ep~bukrs
INTO TABLE covp_itab
FROM cobk AS bk
INNER JOIN coep AS ep ON (bk~kokrs = ep~kokrs AND bk~belnr = ep~belnr)
WHERE bk~kokrs     = co_kokrs
AND   ep~wrttp     = '04'
AND   ep~kstar     IN s_kstar
AND   ep~vrgng     IN s_vrgng 
AND   ep~bukrs     IN r_bukrs
AND   bk~timestamp IN r_stamp.
```

What could possibly be the problem here?

Comment: You probably need more indexes on these tables, but it's hard to tell when you haven't given much information. Have a look at your explain plans.

Comment: There is only a part of the primary key, namely KOKRS used in your query. All the other fields in the selection criteria are non indexed fields. This may be the probable cause. The other might be simple that you have a lot of positions in COEP table. How many records does this table have? In my system there is also quite a number of indices for COEP table. Try to create one consisting of fields (wrttp, kstar, vrgng, bukrs). Remeber that using an index does not come wihout any cost. If the contents of this table change frequently, then probably it is not a good idea to create one.

Comment: Try to include ALL primary key fields in search condition. This will stronlgy speed up select execution. Also, as Jagger correctly stated, in order to make concrete proposals we need to know select execution plan and COBK and COEP rowcount.

Answer (score 1):

As Jagger mentioned, you aren't using any criteria that could utilize any of the standard indexes on either of those tables.  I'd do a combination of things:

- Use SE11 to investigate what indexes are available for COEP and see if you can't possibly formulate a selection (with additional criteria) that will use one of those indexes. It is important to provide data for the fields in order - ie for index COEP~2 the fields are MANDT/OBJNR/KSTAR/GJAHR/PERIO/PAROB1.  If you are unable to provide OBJNR but have KSTAR, GJAHR etc, it will not use the index because you have no OBJNR.  However if you only had MANDT and OBJNR it could potentially use this index.
- Change bk~kokrs to ep~kokrs and change your select to read from COEP and then join COBK.
- For one COEP record that you have the (now) 5 criteria for, go to SE16, enter those selections and run it to see how long it takes.  Be mindful that the query maybe cached and subsequent runs might be faster so try using different values if possible.
- If necessary, create an additional index on COEP.  These come at a cost for inserts and updates so be mindful that just creating an index whenever you have a slow select statement is not a good idea.
- If you create the index but it is not improving the situation, you can find out what indexes (if any) are being used by running an SQL trace using transaction ST05.